# Using Python to parse header string from a file with a unique header printing technique (.inp extension)

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, header

I am looking to use Python to parse a dataframe from a file (for those who might've used, its SWMM model input / inp file). The file header is printed in a rather unique  way which has made it very difficult to completely parse it. An example of the dataframe with the troublesome header) I am trying to read from the file is:

```
;;                                                 Param    
;;Node           Parameter        Time Series      Type     
;;-------------- ---------------- ---------------- -------- 
80408            FLOW             80408            FLOW     
81009            FLOW             81009            FLOW     
82309            FLOW             82309            FLOW
```

The headers are not separated by tabs, or any fixed number of spaces. Also, for some headers when their length is too large, they occupy two vertical lines , while other headers only use one line. The widths are not fixed either, there are more than one such dataframes and they all vary in width.

All I was able to do was grab the bottom-most line as header.

```
 with open(inp_fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
               headers = re.split("\s{2,}", line.replace(';',"").strip())
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at pandas, which has a [reader for fixed-width spreadsheets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Comment: I tried the **pd.read_fwf**, which works for reading the data but does not seem to have any  options to read this type of headers.  If I am missing something, let me know.

Comment: I see; note that you can skip initial lines completely by setting the `skiprows` arguments.

Comment: can't you just check for ';;' and skip them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data doesn't fit the interpolations in `read_fwf` you can scan and parse the header yourself. Once you've worked out column names and widths you can pass them to `read_fwf` with the file pointer open on the first real row. The dashed line separators between header and data is a good indicator for column width, so I used it to calculate column widths.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# write a test file...
open('test.txt', 'w').write("""\
;;                                                 Param    
;;Node           Parameter        Time Series      Type     
;;-------------- ---------------- ---------------- -------- 
80408            FLOW             80408            FLOW     
81009            FLOW             81009            FLOW     
82309            FLOW             82309            FLOW     """)


def make_dataframe(filename):
    with open('test.txt') as fp:
        # grab header
        headers = []
        for line in fp:
            if not line.startswith(';;-'):
                # header line, swap '  ' for ';;' to maintain len
                headers.append('  ' + line[2:-1])
            else:
                break
        else:
            print("ERROR: Header separator not found")
            return None

        # end of header, convert '----' separators to field lengths
        field_lens = [len(m)+1 for m in re.findall(r"\-+", '--' + line[2:-1])]

        # flatten multiline column names
        start = 0
        pd_header = []
        for f_len in field_lens:
            pd_header.append(' '.join(field.strip()
                for field in (h[start:start+f_len] for h in headers)
                if field.strip()))
            start += f_len

        # read fix length columns
        df = pd.read_fwf(fp, header=None, names=pd_header, widths=field_lens,
            index_col=False)
        return df

df = make_dataframe('test.txt')
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked! Its kinda cool to see you use the space among the header separator dash to separate the headers. I had no clue there were spaces there..

Comment: Yes, the challenge was to figure out column widths generically. I've used file formats like this before and didn't even think to mention that's what I was doing. Its useful to point it out!

Answer (score 1):

The same idea as @tdelaney's code, made a bit more concise:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import re
import pandas as pd

def make_dataframe(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        div = []
        headers = list(takewhile(
            lambda x: not x.startswith(';;-') or div.append(x), fp))
        colspecs = [m.span() for m in re.compile("-+").finditer(div[0])]
        headers = [
            re.sub(" +", " ", " ".join(hl[lo : hi] for hl in headers)).strip()
            for lo, hi in colspecs]
        d = pd.read_fwf(fp, header = None,
            colspecs = [(lo - 2, hi - 2) for lo, hi in colspecs])
    d.columns = headers
    return d

print(make_dataframe('test.txt'))
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote it, but thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Prasannadahal You're welcome. I think you have enough rep now.